# Rewrite this equation using cartesian coordiantes $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

In this question the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are given, however I do not know what to substitute in

$x=5t-2\;\quad y=-5t+7$

So far I have rearranged for $t$

$x+2=5t$

$\dfrac{x+2}5=t$

therefore would the next step by $y=-5\left(\dfrac{x+2}5\right)+7$ ?

Comment: Yes, from x= 5t- 2, 5t= x+ 2 so t= (x+ 2)/5. (NOT t= x+ 2/5!.)  But, since both x and y involve 5t,  it is simplest not to solve for t itself.  5t= x+ 2 so y= -5t+ 7= -(x+ 2)+ 7= -x+ 5.

Comment: What @GeorgeIvey commented.  Note that each equation contains a $(5t)$ *term*, and does not contain any other terms that in any way involve the variable $(t)$.

Comment: So we multiply out giving us -5x-10/5+7 and then that equals to -x-2+7?

Comment: The question is "What does y equal?".   You seem to have lost the "y".  "y" is NOT -x- 2+ 7.

Comment: y=-x+5 from what i calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=5t-2$

$x+2=5t$

$\dfrac{x+2}5=t$

$y=-5t+7$

$y=-5\left(\dfrac{x+2}5\right)+7$

$y=-(x+2)+7$

$y=-x-2+7$

$y=-x+5$